# How to reinstall stock firmware on Galaxy S4 SCH-I545

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-s-4

I rooted my phone to get rid of bloatware and free up internal storage.  It worked but then I uninstalled the root app and my phone was having issues.

I did a factory restore and now when moving through the setup wizard it throws an error  "unfortunately, setup wizard has stopped" and starts back at beginning of setup wizard.

Any idea how to reinstall the stock firmware to get my phone going again?

Edit:

```
<ID:0/004> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/004> aboot.mbn
<ID:0/004> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/004> 
<ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)
```

Comment: Did you try flashing with *Odin programming tool*?

Comment: I tried to use Odin but it failed.

Comment: Is it possible to show us what errors you get? Should help understand what is going on

Comment: <ID:0/004> Added!!
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<ID:0/004> Odin engine v(ID:3.1203)..
<ID:0/004> File analysis..
<ID:0/004> SetupConnection..
<ID:0/004> Initialzation..
<ID:0/004> Get PIT for mapping..
<ID:0/004> Firmware update start..
<ID:0/004> SingleDownload.
<ID:0/004> aboot.mbn
<ID:0/004> FAIL! (Auth)
<ID:0/004> 
<ID:0/004> Complete(Write) operation failed.
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 1)

Comment: From the log, I can tell you are trying to flash a wrong firmware file intended for another variant. This model has 2 variants IIRC.

Comment: Thanks...I'm trying to find the correct variant now.  The model number inside the batter case is listed as SCH-i545 UD but I'm not finding much under that search.

Comment: Try booting to Download mode (Volume down + Home + power button) The model should be there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78072/discussion-between-mike-oberdick-and-esqmo).